# What causes these patchwork lines in the resulting image from my scanner?

Tags: scanner, image-processing

I'm trying to scan some old trading cards (AD&D Trading Cards from 1991) and I'm having trouble getting a good scan result on a flat bed scanner.

The issue I'm having is the resulting image appears as a patchwork that is not lined up properly.

Here is a zoomed in portion of a 1200dpi scan on my Canon CanoScan LiDE 210:

[image]

I tried buying a more recent scanner, an Epson Perfection V39 with the same problem but with a different representation or place:

[image]

Rotating the card in the scanner only changes the orientation of the artifact:

[image]

What is causing this artifact across manufacturers?

Comment: 1) top photo error looks diagonal, have you rotated the image before posting? (normally I would expect something like this to be correlated to the movement of the scanner wand during the scanning process.); 2) have you tested to see if this is related to the scan resolution? ( https://www.parkablogs.com/picture/artist-review-canon-lide-400-flatbed-scanner ) suggests it might be resolution dependent. Noting that model has an "auto-stitch" feature, my first thought is that the driver is, for buffer or memory reasons, stitching partial scans when the memory requirement for the full scan is high

Comment: The fact that the first image has diagonal artifacting is actually very interesting. I aligned the card lengthwise (the orientation of the card aligns with the orientation of the scan bed) and placed it close to the origin arrow. I would expect there to be buffering as you suggested; the scan resolution I'm using is very high and is expected to outpace the buffer. I don't understand why there should be a problem aligning the end of one buffer with the start of the next unless there is a problem in the firmware.

Comment: Yes the diagonal artifact is confusing. An argument against firmware is that it occurs across model and manufacturer so probably e.g. WIA/TWAIN/{magic}. Not sure what OS you are using, but I am wondering if you set up a virtual machine with Linux and tried the SANE interface you might rule out the software interface

Comment: And a completely off-the-wall thought: how stable is the surface the scanner is on and have you tried buffering the surface from vibration?

Comment: @Yorik The surface is stable and there is very little movement at all to cause vibration. At a high DPI setting, the bed is already moving very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't see any obvious flaw in the scan, likely any imperfection is due to [the moiré effect](https://photographylife.com/what-is-moire), caused by two overlapping patterns.

In your case, the playing cards are [halftone prints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone), and the scanner sensor is a linear array of RGB photosensors. To get a more accurate image, you'd need a scanner with finer pitch, i.e. more dots per millimeter.

Also, to identify a printer (and perhaps a scanner), a [machine identification code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Identification_Code) may add some artifacts. This also helps prevent counterfeiting documents.

Finally, friction ("[stiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiction)") causes slip/stick in mechanical devices. Since flatbed scanners move the scan head along rails, there may be occasional jumps in the scan. This effect is most pronounced in a device that has not been used in some time, since use redistributes lubricant and may remove specks of dust on the rails. Properly cleaning and lubricating a scanner calls for special equipment, e.g., a [cleanroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleanroom), to prevent getting more dirt in the mechanism than was removed, so I don't recommend you do any repairs beyond that shown in the scanner shop manual.

Comment: I've updated the question with another example. While the artifacting does appear in the moire area, it is consistent across a solid background. I am also scanning at a high enough resolution that there is no moire effect-- it's picking up the halftones directly which is expected and not part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We've had the same scanners and the same issues!

I also got a newer Canon LiDE and after it had the same problems I discussed the issue with their tech support. I was told the lines are caused by small gaps between the scanning elements, and that it is not one continuous element.

The issue seemed much worse on newer model than old one (my old scanner only appeared to have one or no lines, while the new one had multiple of these lines), and the degree of the misaligned lines can vary.

Epson v39 had same issue.

I'm disappointed that these reportedly high quality photo scanners have such significant and apparent issues with their primary function.

Comment: This is actually a decent answer. It brings new and pertinent information from the scanner manufacture support regarding a likely physical defect in the scanner causing this issue. I have edited it to focus on the helpful info.